# update the value in set Python?

Tags: python, set

Here an example of my set, which I would like to update:

```
>>> x = set()
>>> x.add(('A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564', 1, 0))
>>> x
set([('A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564', 1, 0)])
```

My expected result would be:

```
set([('A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564', 1, 1)])
```

How I can do it? Is a set is the best option, or have I to use another data structure for that? I thought that update method in `set` can do that. However, I made mistake, and that is not a good solution as it does not consider the first parameter as a key and repeat the elements.

Comment: And how would you go about *identifying* what needed changing?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I am not sure what I have to do, this is the first time i am using set. Am I need to have a loop inside my set for updating with the new value? because the first element should remain the same and other two elements are changing.

Comment: So why are you using a set in the first place?

Comment: If only the first element of your tuple is unique, don't use a set, use a dictionary.

Comment: I just want to avoid of repetitive id.

Comment: Then a set is the wrong type to use. Use that if the *whole tuple* must be unique. You want only *one element* to be unique, and track some extra data. Use a dictionary.

Comment: Do u mean if I need to have a update for the rest of my element , set is not a good option?

Comment: Indeed, sets should only be used if the *whole object* is unchanging.

Comment: @MartijnPieters let me I update my question. Helps to be more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to *remove* the element from the set, and add a new element with that value updated. That's because sets use *hashing* to efficiently eliminate duplicates. If mutating the elements directly was allowed you'd break this model.

I think you only want the *first element* to be unique, and track some data associated with that first element. If so you want to use a *dictionary* instead; use the first element as a key to map to the other two values, in a list for easy altering:

```
>>> x = {}
>>> x['A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564'] = [1, 0]
>>> x['A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564'][1] += 1  # increment the second element.
>>> x
{'A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564': [1, 1]}
```

Keys in a dictionary also must be unique.

Note that `set.update()` only gives you a *union* operation; the set is updated in-place by adding all elements from the argument(s) that are not already in the set. `set.update()` cannot alter elements already in the set, because elements the set should not be altered (or at least not in ways that change their hash and equality).

Comment: I have updated my question. Thank u for any more comment ;)

Comment: @MaryamPashmi: that question update wasn't needed; there is nothing materially different about nesting this inside a dictionary.

Comment: @MaryamPashmi: you can put dictionaries as values inside other dictionaries, just like you can put sets as values in dictionaries.

Comment: So , do u mean is exactly the same, I mean using nested dic?

Comment: How can I update that then? dic inside another dictionary, if u can add this to your answer I will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, just use `outerdict['prefix1']['A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564']` to access the list I proposed in my answer; `outerdict['prefix1']['A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564'][1] += 1` would update the second integer in that list.

Comment: so, for that I need to have two loop , right , for each key? This is not affecting on performance?

Comment: @MaryamPashmi: I have no idea what you are trying to do with all these values. Nested loops are fine, if you need to process all ids for all prefixes you have no other option.

Comment: ok. yes. I have to process all the prefixes, all the ids,... thank u for your answer;)

Answer (score 2):

You are better off using a `dict` if you are trying to have keys and values and you want to update based on key:

```
x = {'A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564' : [1, 0]}

x['A1760ulorenaf0821x151031175821564'] = [1, 1]
```